# Calculating 2 whole factors from a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, fractions, decimal-expansion

I've been out of school for a very long time, and can't wrap my head around calculating 2 whole numbers from a fraction.  For instance, if I have 2 ratios --

```
4:3    1.33333...
16:9   1.77777...
?:?    (automatically generated)
```

I want to be able to look up the whole number representations from a decimal point.(for a software program)  I think there should be a fairly easy way to do this?  I've seen some other questions possibly linked to this, however, I can't read math anymore either, so text answers would be wonderful :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a straightforward algorithm for this. Allow me to demonstrate on

$$ 0.1\overline{37} = 0.1373737373737\ldots$$

The first step is to split off the non-repeating part:

$$ 0.1\overline{37} = 0.1 + 0.0\overline{37} $$

then you pull out the 'common factor' from the repeated part

$$ 0.1\overline{37} = 0.1 + 37 \cdot 0.0\overline{01} $$

then you multiply and divide by an appropriate number to make the repeated part all 9's

$$ 0.1\overline{37} = 0.1 + \frac{37}{99} \cdot 0.0\overline{99} $$

then you simplify repeated 9's:

$$ 0.1\overline{37} = 0.1 + \frac{37}{99} \cdot 0.1 $$

with practice you can do all of the above in a single step. Once here, you can simplify further if you need to

$$ 0.1\overline{37} = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{37}{99} \cdot \frac{1}{10}
= \frac{68}{495} $$

---

If you need to do this in software rather than by hand, this is an example of the "rational reconstruction" problem, and some languages have solutions built-in. e.g. in `python`, you can use the [fractions](http://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction('0.13737373737').limit_denominator()
Fraction(68, 495)
```

although it takes some care to ensure that you get the right make sure you get it right. e.g. the default settings would give the wrong answer if I just used `'0.1373737'`.

The general algorithm is [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fractions), and it will work even when the part you have doesn't repeat, assuming you give enough information. The `python` example I mention above uses this method (I believe), and it can recover the fraction $1/7$ from a decimal approximation:

```
>>> Fraction('0.1428').limit_denominator(100)
Fraction(1,7)
```

Comment: Thanks for tips.  limit_denominator is awesome.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can compute it. Multiply the decimal by $10^n$, where $n$ is the number of digits in the repeat of the decimal and subtract. Example: given $ x=5.181818\ldots \\100x=518.1818\ldots,\\99x=513,\\x=\frac{513}{99}$

Comment: ok i love this answer.  effectively it is almost the same as the slightly earlier one but it is so damn pretty.

Comment: Thanks, this made it easier for me to understand.  Next is how to determine repeating decimals .......

Comment: @ansiart:  If you aren't guaranteed to have a repeat, you can't be sure.  How long would you keep trying $0.181818181818181819$ before you decided the repeat was $18$?  How about $0.142857$ (which is the repeat of $\frac 17$) but you only got one period?  These are not mathematical questions.

Comment: Thanks Ross, yeah, I'll ask that elsewhere.  Thanks again for your help.